# Card Verifiable Certificates Creation, Signing and Exporting Tools?

Tags: openssl, smartcard

Good day,

I have gotten a task at work which has turned out to be a rather interesting nightmare because of the lack of Information on the topic.

My task is as follows: In order to ensure an asymmetric administration of the chip-card on the field. An authentication CVC-Certificate must be imported inside the card via "PSO Commands". The CVC Certificate must be signed by the CVC-Root Certification Authority and posses the OID defined for Card-Administration.

I have all the cryptographic material needed for the task except the CVC-Certificate. I have the definitions of how the CVC-Certificate should look and how the information needs to be coded. My problem is I have never worked with anything else than X.509-Certificates and the OpenSSL CLI because of this and my lack of experience on the subject the following questions rise...

How do you create a CVC-PKCS#10?

How can you sign it with the help of OPENSSL and the CVC-Root Certificate?

How does one output a CVC-Certificate?

It is my first question in this kind of boards so if you see a mistake or need more Information on the matter let me know.

Thanks in advance for all your input.

Comment: The tag `cvcs` is misleading, even if it uses a similar abbreviation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PSO (i. e. Perform Security Operation) in the mode verify certificate (short VCERT) is described in ISO 7816, part 8. Due to my knowledge, there is no easily downloadable copy on the internet.

The principle is simple: the root key has to be selected previously (Manage Security environment, ISO 7816, part 4). Then you send a BER-TLV encoded string as command data field in a PSO VCERT command. The CV certificate is separated on top level into the new public key and signature. (I don't understand the *output* issue; it is just concatentation of the respective data objects with proper length fields.) If the signature matches, the card discards it and keeps the new public key for subsequent use. You will also require substantial documentation from your card supplier, how the root key is selected.

I'm afraid, that neither OpenSSL nor PKCS#10 will be of much use. The signature (assuming RSA) is not much more than a RSA-operation on a properly padded byte string. In any case you will likely need to communicate with the card on APDU level directly, first for verifying the certificate and then for the application of the respective key.

Comment: Hi Guidot, thank you for your answer. I am aware of the ISO/IEC 7816-4. The card in dispute is a card that we have personalized ourselves and has in it's file structure the public key of our Root-CVC Authority. The steps that Im supposed to take to ensure an assymetric administration of the card are as follows: 1. MSE SET (Public Key By Reference)  2. Import Authentication CVC Certificate signed by the Root-CVC Authority with PSO Verify Command ( I don't have this certificate, but have access to the private key) 3. MSE SET(Smartcard Private Key) 4. General Authenticate Step 1 and 2.

Comment: This is where my question rises, I own the root private key therefore I should be able to create and sign the authentication cvc. Im just missing the tools and a deeper understanding. Im dwelving into the bouncycastle api and java I saw the api has some interesting classes in regards to building CVC.  I will update on this in the next days.

Comment: @Manfredovik Has your research given any insights into how CVC certs can be created?

Comment: @always_a_rookie Depending on the specification used you have to encode the CVC using the TLV Encoding  scheme with fixed or maximum field sizes. Programmatically speaking you would use a bytearray where each byte consists of the Tag, the length of the value and the value itself.  Since there is more than one element (CA, Owner, Public Key, etc...) you would concatenate more than one bytearray till you have a complete CVC body. You can then sign the body and append the signature to have a Card Verifiable Certificate.